# Generate PDF fynamically vs store it in file system?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, pdf, architecture

I'm developing PHP/MySQL application that will create small PDF files - barcode labels with some additional text, and simple 1-2 pages text documents for customers. These PDF's will be accessed 1-3 times in day, when created, but should remain archived, for later access which would be very rare, let's say 1 of 500 will be accessed during later year.

My question is - should I store them in file system or generate on demand? I would consider to generate them dynamically, because during peek there will be generated 1000-5000 barcodes/day, and storing this junk just for occasional retrieval would just waste of server space.

Comment: Sounds like you've already made the right decision. If you hardly ever need them again, generating them on the fly will likely be better. And it also saves you from having to write extra code to do the saving and retrieving. You can just generate the pdf as if it was never generated before.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is - should I store them in file system or generate on
>   demand?

Do both. Save them but do it with a caching scheme so anything older than—let’s say—1 hour gets trashed & regenerated. That way you alleviate the pressure on your server to generate a bar code for each request, but don’t have to worry about permanent storage. The caching scheme should be based on your needs, but a setup like this allows you to balance the benefits of dynamic generation plus the file system all at once.

Also, if you log records of how many times barcode data is accessed you could allow the items that are more popular to be cached longer.

Comment: actually... ^this is a better option. Caching may seem like a ballsache to implement but in the long run you'll have best of both worlds.

Comment: Thank you, Jake! That's a brilliant idea with log analysis.

Comment: really? The generation of a 1 to 2 page document to PDF from source using a properly implemented technology would take less time than it takes for the Adobe PDF Plug-in to launch in a browser. In our system tests for documents, anything less than 10-15 pages is shown on the screen as fast as 1 page and as fast as the same file read from disk.

Answer (score 1):

If they are rarely to be used and don't take a long time to generate then just do it on the fly.

But if your users will be more irritated by waiting to view PDFs rather than waiting for them to be created then better to store them (and probably along with a jpg preview already created)